# physical addresses on the same rank/bank

Tags: arm, hardware, armv8

I'have been trying to understand how to get two physical addresses mapped in the same bank.
Given two physical addresses how can i know if they are on the same bank ?
My first question is : supponing to have addr1 and addr2 with the same physical page number, are they mapped on the same bank ?

i'm working on a ARMv8 architecture running linux.

Thank you.

Comment: arm has nothing to do with the dram controller and system implementation, very far removed from it.

Comment: you have to read up on the chip (arm does not make chips either) and dram, etc.  often the details are protected by NDA, but you might get lucky.  What did you find when you looked at the dram controller for the chip in question?

Comment: I didn't look at DRAM controller, i mean i was wondering how ti can doi it given two physical addresses.

Comment: it is specific to the dram controller, and/or the chip logic that feeds the dram controller, possibly configurable within the chip so specific to that configuration, none of which is related to arm.

Comment: What chip is this and what did the documentation say?

Comment: row address, column address, bank address and rank are going to come from specific bits in the physical address that comes from the arm through the chips logic and land in the dram controller. amount of ram, etc plus again possible configure options in the dram controller will determine what that map looks like no reason to assume that any two systems do it the same way.